# Filter categories using tags

Tags: categories, filters, tags

I have a website with the following categories:

- Videos
- Pictures
- Stories

And I have a lot of tags like: `Funny`, `Awesome`, `Mind Blowing`, `Crazy`, etc.

Is there a way I could filter lets say: `Videos` tagged as `Crazy`?

I know you can do:

```
http://domainname.com/tag/crazy/
```

But that would retrieve ALL content tagged as `crazy`, I just want `Videos`.

I've searched the WordPress documentation without luck.

Comment: You've gotten two straight answers. The question is what type of navigation do you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way that @toscho's solution made me try, and worked for me, is this scheme:

```
http://example.com/videos/?tag=crazy
```

Comment: This method is much more elegant. @toscho's answer was more direct to the URL structure in question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the category as parameter:

```
http://example.com/tag/crazy?category=videos
```

This will list only the posts tagged `crazy` from category `videos`. Be aware the conditional tags will treat this as tag archive.